# How can we invoke one external service once transaction is done

Tags: corda

currently I am working on one work that once the transaction is done, we need to send out one notification for both sender and recipient users. This notification service will be a non-corda service, sender and recipient should invoke this external service by themselves. Our thought is in Corda code, there is one place that we can know the transaction is done or data is already stored into ledger correct, and this place code is applicable for both sender and recipient. But we haven't found this code yet. Anyone can provide some guidance here? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use:

```
fun waitForLedgerCommit(hash: SecureHash): SignedTransaction
```

This takes an input the hash of a transaction, and suspends the flow until the transaction with this hash has been verified and sent to the vault for processing.